# Is it possible to define my own Show class and reuse instances of TextShow and Prelude.Show?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm trying to define my own `Show` class named `MyShow`, and want to 'steal' instances from `TextShow`  and `Prelude.Show`, and prefer the former one if both exists.

I tried following (`showbPrec` things is simplified to be focused):

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Text (Text, pack, unpack)
import qualified Prelude as P
import qualified TextShow as T

class MyShow a where
    showText :: a -> Text

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} TextShow a => MyShow a where
    showText x = T.showt x

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} P.Show a => MyShow a where
    showText x = pack (P.show x)
```

But I'm telled that *Duplicate instance declarations* is not allowed, so is there any way to define my own `Show` and reuse instances from others?

Comment: You can reuse instances, but you need to be explicit which one should be used for each type. It _might_ be possibly to get something like this working with `-XIncoherentInstances`, but that's a pure evil extension that almost guarantees nasty surprises elsewhere.

Comment: The problem is that you can _never_ be sure that a type is not an instance of some class, because it is always possible that somebody else would add the instance further downstream. Normal overlapping instances exploit the fact that you _can_ be sure that e.g. `Maybe a` doesn't match `[b]`, but in your example nothing like this is given.

Comment: The actual answer is writing a newtype for each, and optionally implement default methods.

Comment: @Iceland_jack  Sounds promising!  could you please provide a concrete example and post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't let you branch on which instance is available, that goes against the open-world assumption where adding a new instance should not change the behaviour of your program. There are ways of doing this kind of branching, one approach is the compiler plugin [`IfSat`](https://github.com/sheaf/if-instance) but this is not the normal way of doing it.

```
newtype AsShow a = AsShow a

instance P.Show a => MyShow (AsShow a) where
  showText :: AsShow a -> Text
  showText (AsShow a) = pack (P.show a)

newtype AsTextShow a = AsTextShow a

instance TextShow a => MyShow (AsTextShow a) where
  showText :: AsTextShow a -> Text
  showText (AsTextShow a) = showt a
```

With these newtypes you can then derive instances for your `MyShow` using `DerivingVia`

```
{-# Language DerivingVia #-}
{-# Language StandaloneDeriving #-}

-- standalone deriving for types defined elsewhere
deriving via AsShow Int     instance MyShow Int
deriving via AsShow Integer instance MyShow Integer

data BOOL = FALSE | TRUE
  deriving
  stock P.Show

  deriving MyShow
  via AsShow BOOL
```